# C compilation error, called object is not a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have the following code in C to make some arithmatic calculation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float x,y;
    float z;
    printf("Enter x y z \n");
    scanf("%f %f %f ", &x, &y , &z);
    z = ((4.2 (x+y)))/ (z - (0.25*z))/ (y+z)/ ((x+y) * (x+y));
    printf("\n z = %f", z);
    return 0;
}
```

when i build the program , i get the following error message in the following code line

```
z = ((4.2 (x+y)))/ (z - (0.25*z))/ (y+z)/ ((x+y) * (x+y));
```

called object is not a function or dunction pointer

Comment: You miss something after 4.2

Comment: There should be an operator after 4.2

Comment: `4.2(x+y)` might be what you've learned in school but in C you have to use `4.2*(x+y)` instead of the other one

Answer (score 3):

That's a **typo**, you're missing an operator:

```
z = ((4.2 * (x + y))) / (z - (0.25*z)) / (y + z) / ((x + y) * (x + y));
          ^
          whatever the operator is
```

C has no support for mathematics-implicit multiplication operator (more or less as you would write in an equation in school). E.g.

```
// y = 2x
int y;
y = 2 * x;
```